# Dump a process's entire state to disk and load back when required

Tags: .net, process, snapshot, disk, coredump

I have a c# application that accepts jobs based on multiple events

Like file watcher, time based events etc.

But an time would come in the life cycle of the application that it would process resources partially, take them in the RAM. And then will wait for an event to happen. But until that event the process would hold the 1.2 GB RAM(say).

In this time the process cannot be killed and this process has to accept more jobs.

My question:

Can we dump the entire state of this process to the disk and on a later point(say 6 hrs later) when that event would happen, restart the process using that dump file so that the entire state gets loaded and then "continue" the execution from that point.

Using
.net 4.0
Vs2010/vs2015
C#

I read this : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/d5zhxt22.aspx#

But continuing the process isn't an option.

Please advice

Comment: If all threads in the process are waiting and nothing's touching memory, practically all of the memory will be paged out to the page file anyway. Processes don't (usually) consume RAM - they consume their own address space. The OS decides what gets to use the physical memory, so long as you let it do so.

Comment: maybe i didnt explain it well. suppose a 800 mb file has just been processed. now its stored in a dictionary. and i have to wait until that event  happens so that another file can be read and hence merged. the process will consume RAM i guess.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever : could you please advice.